# Auto-Merge doesn't work

Tags: modeling

I don't know why but Auto-Merge doesn't work. I'm trying to AutoMerge vertices and it doesn't do anything.

Do I need to do anything to activate it?

Blend:

[image]

Comment: I have increased it to it's max which is 1m and it does nothing. It feels like it doesn't even work.

Comment: please show some screenshots or even share your file

Comment: I added a blend file of the default scene since it doesn't even work on the default cube.

Comment: Nvm. It just started working now. Not sure what was going on but now it's working.

Comment: sorry I confused Auto-Merge with Merge by Distance, I hope my answer will help

Comment: It's working fine on the default cube in the file you downloaded. I've reduced the number of verts from 8 to 7 just by edge sliding a vert until it reached another vert. Which version of Blender are you using and what does "doesn't work mean"? (Describe what you tried, what you expected, and what happened, please.)

Answer (score 1):

The *Auto-Merge* option won't make the vertices snap. Activate the *Snap to Vertex* option and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when you want to snap and merge:

[image]

Comment: You don't need snapping to bring verts close enough together to auto merge, of course.  I've managed to merge verts in the OP's file both by moving a vert by eye and by edge sliding.

Comment: I've always used snapping with auto merge, sure you can merge without it but it's a bit tedious no? Or I'm missing something...

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, I think it's a matter of workflows.  Since I tend to use edge slide to merge, I don't find it tedious, but if snapping is more general.

Comment: Ok but I thought that the OP was expecting a kind of snapping

Answer (score 1):

[Auto Merge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/tool_settings.html#auto-merge-vertices) does require that you enable it; but you've done so already in your blend file.  You can check this in the sidebar in the Tool tab:

[image: Auto merge enabled]

And I've checked, it does work in your file.  If I move any vertex close enough to another vertex that it's connected to by an edge, they do merge.  I suspect that your problem is either that you're trying to merge vertices that aren't connected by edges, or that your simply not getting close enough.

In [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/256803/42221) Moonboots points out one way to make it easy to get close.  I use a different one, [*edge sliding*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_slide.html), short cut <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and left click to finish.  Both of those work in your file.

I've also "eyeballed" a move and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to have *Split Edges & Faces* turned on in order to make *Auto Merge* work.

[image]